# Python selenium screen capture not getting whole page

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

I am trying to create a generic webcrawler that will go to a site and take a screenshot. I am using Python, Selnium, and PhantomJS. The problem is that the screenshot is not capturing all the images on a page. For example, if I go to you tube, it doesn't capture images below the main page image. (I don't have high enough rep to post screen shot) I think this may have something to do with dynamic content, but I have tried the wait functions such as implicitly wait and on set_page_load_timeout methods. Because this is a generic crawler I can't wait for a specific event (I want to crawl hundreds of sites).

Is it possible to create a generic webcrawler that can do the screen capture I am trying to do? Code I am using is:

```
phantom = webdriver.PhantomJS()
phantom.set_page_load_timeout(30)
phantom.get(response.url)
img = phantom.get_screenshot_as_png() #64-bit encoded string
phantom.quit
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lonZz.png)

Comment: The solution is probably increasing the viewportSize, then scrolling down the page and finally waiting a bit.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906704/taking-a-whole-page-screenshot-with-selenium-marionette-in-python/42531572

Answer (score 4):

Your suggestion solved the problem. Used the following code (stolen in part from answer to another question):

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()    
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://youtube.com')  
scheight = .1
while scheight < 9.9:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/%s);" % scheight)
    scheight += .01        
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Comment: Well, code-only answers aren't *very* helpful for others. Please explain ***why** you're doing this and **how** does this work*.

Comment: some working code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906704/taking-a-whole-page-screenshot-with-selenium-marionette-in-python/42531572

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/57338909/2943191 for more information if you run into problems.