# Convert a full webpage to a PDF or combine screenshots into one image

Tags: python-3.x, screenshot

I am looking for convert a webpage to a PDF. I searched this like "take screenshot of all webpage". In everywhere, everybody refers python "selenium" module. But didn't find anything about "all page". Don't want to a single screenshot. My whis is like PDF format.

Already tried to imgkit. Is there any option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. First module's name is "Selenium-Screenshot".It takes screenshots and compare them in 1 image. For more detailed discussion:
[Taking a whole page screenshot with Selenium Marionette in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906704/taking-a-whole-page-screenshot-with-selenium-marionette-in-python)

```
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping
from selenium import webdriver

ob=Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()   #created for headless chrome
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')    #change resolution of screenshots

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
url = "your_url"
driver.get(url)
img_url=ob.full_Screenshot(driver, save_path=r'.', image_name='Myimage.png')
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that there is something called pdfkit, also a wkhtmltopdf wrapper for python.

https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit

Alternatively I would recommend CutyCapt, that is if it does not have to be a python library.

http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually it does. I'm trying to do this with python because i need this feature in my program. Little bit challenging for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i got some ugly errors on that. But i found my answer