# Take screenshot of full web page with Selenium Python with Chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to take a screenshot of the full page of a website. Below are the website conditions

1. It requires authentication with a sign in form
2. The website I want to screenshot is rendered by Javascript (dynamic rendering), not static rendering
   (inside the `body` tag is just `script` tags)

I did try some solutions I can find, but none of them work as I desired. Below are some attempt I tried

1. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721734/take-screenshot-of-full-page-with-selenium-python-with-chromedriver) This one required using headless chrome, which make me unable to fill the sign in form
2. When I try to remove the headless options, I get this error `"message":"Cannot take screenshot with 0 height."`I guess this is because the content is rendered by Javascript. Note that I already give it some time to render with `time.sleep(5)`
3. When I try to choose another element, the result is varying. Some gives same error message as above, some give me the screenshot but not full page, just the visible part (same result as using `browser.save_screenshot()`). Below is the code I tried.

```js
def S(X): return browser.execute_script(
                'return document.querySelector("#main-layout-content").scroll'+X
)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('some link go here')
browser.set_window_size(S('Width') + 100, S('Height') + 1000)
#The print statement below work
print(S('Height')) 
browser.find_element_by_id('main-layout-content').screenshot('web_screenshot.png')
```

Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Comment: _This one required using headless chrome, which make me unable to fill the sign in form_ Why can't you fill in the form using a headless browser?

Comment: "_The content I want to screenshot_" /  "_Take screenshot of full web page_" - which on is it? it's an element or the full page? Without the actual url, will be difficult to get help.

Comment: @PedroLobito you can use a Youtube link (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1F_OgqRuSdI&list=PL0-84-yl1fUnRuXGFe_F7qSH1LEnn9LkW) ). I want to take a screenshot of full web page.

Comment: You best shot is still `PhantomJS`. I tried several browsers and couldn't take a decent screenshot of the full webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to get the full-size screenshot of a webpage

```python
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# We go to the webpage here and wait 2 seconds for fully load
browser.get('https://someURL')
time.sleep(2)

# Where to save the picture
directory = '/home'
# Video title
title = 'Hello world'

try:
        # We try to get the top-level component in which all out page is its children
        # This is different for each website
        elem = browser.find_element_by_id('main-layout-content')
        # Get the height of the element, and adding some height just to be sage
        total_height = elem.size['height'] + 1000
        # Set the window size - what is the size of our screenshot
        # The width is hardcoded because the screensize is fixed for each computer
        browser.set_window_size(1920, total_height)
        # Wait for 2 seconds
        time.sleep(2)
        # Take the screenshot
        browser.find_element_by_id(
            'main-layout-content').screenshot(f'./{directory}/{title}.png')
except SystemError as err:
        print('Take screenshot error at' + title)
```