# Python - Full page screenshot with Selenium with extension enabled

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open Chrome in non-headless mode with an extension enabled to take a full page screenshot. When I remove headless mode, the extension works but the taken fullscreen is not for the full page. Without headless mode, the extension cannot be loaded.

I came across this answer which mentions that it is not possible without headless option. However, extensions cannot be enabled in headless option.

[Take screenshot of full page with Selenium Python with chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721734/take-screenshot-of-full-page-with-selenium-python-with-chromedriver/57338909#57338909)

here is my current code. Is there away to do this?

```
print("Taking screenshot for {}".format(link))
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('./chromedrivers/AdblockPlus.zip')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
#options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome("{}/chromedrivers/{}".format("macDriver"),options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

driver.get(link)
S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
driver.set_window_size(S('Width'), S('Height'))                                                                                                             
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(f'./screenshots/{name}.png')
```

Comment: I think there are tools that claim to take full page screen shots (like https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug perhaps)

Comment: Sorry, removed my answer. Misunderstood and didn't see that you explicitly wanted it in non-headless mode

Comment: @DMart it seems that this library is only in Java?