# Selenium does not take the screenshot of the whole website, when its not headless

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Disclaimer: I know, that there is a similar question already, but none of the answers works for headless browser, so I have decided to make 1 more and a bit more detailed one (the question I have mentioned: [Take screenshot of full page with Selenium Python with chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721734/take-screenshot-of-full-page-with-selenium-python-with-chromedriver))

Hello everyone.

I have stumbled upon a quite easy looking, yet hard to solve problem. I need to take a screenshot of a NON-HEADLESS BROWSER on a display, that is 1920x1080 (will be important later) that is going to make a screenshot of the whole webpage, not only the part that you can currently see.

What have I tried:

```
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chromedriver = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'chromedriver.exe')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

chrome.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

total_height = chrome.execute_script("return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight") + 1000

chrome.set_window_size(1920, total_height)

time.sleep(2)
chrome.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
chrome.quit()
```

^ this one, with Headless works perfectly fine, unfortunately, when I remove the `--headless` option, selenium will try to resize itself, but since its trying to resize above the `1080` (`height` of the display) its immediately adjusted to the `1080` which leads to a screenshot `1920x1080`. What I need in a "theoretical" way is to make selenium go `headless` only for the moment, when its taking the screenshot (that unfortunatelly to my knowledge is not possible).

Other commonly used methods that does not work when browser is not headless:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
el.screenshot(path)
```

```
original_size = driver.get_window_size()
required_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
required_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(path)  # avoids scrollbar
driver.set_window_size(original_size['width'], original_size['height'])
```

```
element = chrome.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
element_png = element.screenshot_as_png
with open("test2.png", "wb") as file:
    file.write(element_png)
```

With `headless` option

[image: With headless option]

Without `headless` option

[image: Without headless option]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Screenshot_Clipping in order to scroll the page and take screenshot from each scroll.

Just run this command in python3

```
pip install Selenium-Screenshot
```

Then create an object of Screenshot:

```
ob=Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()
```

With that object you can use `ob.full_Screenshot` in order to capture full screen

Checkout [PythonFullPageScreenShot](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects/tree/main/PythonFullPageScreenShot) project on Github for full source code

Note that screenshot can take only 10000 of height of website, You can scale to 100 in order to capture full height

Comment: Hi, The answer seems to be working the way I wanted it to work. Altho, I have a question regarding it ... is there a simple way how to make that screenshot not to be cut ? (there are a few places of the page that are missing. I have played with "viewport" width a height, but it doesnt look like its working. Thx in advance :)

Comment: found out how to do it right I typed that message :D ... didnt notice that I can easily manipulate the `viewport_height`. Thank you for the answer ! Altho it would be nice if it could be somehow automated