# Selenium + Firefox headless: larger window heights not set correctly

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I need to capture a screenshot of a page with a mobile viewport width. The window height needs to be ~18000px to include all the content on the page without scrolling.

Every time I call `set_window_size()`, `get_window_size()` reports a smaller height and my screenshots are cut off:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

fox_options = Options()
fox_options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=fox_options)
driver.get("https://foo.bar")

driver.set_window_size(450, 18355)
driver.get_window_size()
>> {'width': 450, 'height': 16384}
```

Smaller heights are set correctly. There doesn't seem to be a hard height limit, I can create even larger windows when opening larger pages with more content, but the window is always ~2000px smaller than it needs to be.

I tried:

- Adding 2000 to the height passed to `set_window_size()`, no effect.
- `set_window_position(0, 0)` before `set_window_size()`, no effect.
- Older versions of Firefox + geckodriver (77.0.1, 0.26.0): **this DOES WORK**, but not an option.

Versions: Selenium 4.1.0, geckodriver 0.30.0, Firefox 96.0.

Is this a bug in newer versions? Does anyone have a workaround?

Alternative ways of capturing the entire page would be good too, but the methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721734/take-screenshot-of-full-page-with-selenium-python-with-chromedriver) don't work for various reasons.

Comment: headless mode always renders a smaller window. can you confirm if this worked fine on headless mode of previous version as well?

Comment: @Hammad yes, the exact same headless test was run on both versions.