# Python selenium wont print entire page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the html code from a web page but I only get like 1/4 of the page showing.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.hltv.org/matches")

print(driver.page_source)
```

It feels like I have tried everything but still get the same result. It doesn't start at the top. It starts far far down, almost at the end.

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python selenium screen capture not getting whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211056/python-selenium-screen-capture-not-getting-whole-page)

Comment: I dont want to screencapture. I am looking for the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. this worked for me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.hltv.org/matches")
file = open("asd.html", "a", encoding='utf8')
file.write(driver.page_source)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your get has not finished loading the page at the time that your printing is happening.

To fix this you could try waiting for a known element to load before printing.

To wait for an element ("backToLoginDialog" in the example below) to load, adjust your code to be like the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# set up driver and page load timeout
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
timeout = 5

# create your "wait" function
def wait_for_load(element_id):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, element_id))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

driver.get('https://www.hltv.org/matches')
wait_for_load('backToLoginDialog')
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Did not get it to work. I am no expert so this code probably works but got a few errors. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I made an edit (forgot to include WebDriverWait ) in previous version. This worked fine on my system, copying and pasting straight from this post - I also found 'backToLoginDialog" on the page itself to test for the load. Looks like you got a solution in any case though :)